# NSString Format issue automatically append \x

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

i found something like this was not expected

code

`NSString *strCrown2 = @"T-#-B-DAC";`

when i put break point there and check i found like below image

[image]

There is \x , it is not part of string

in console it is displaying  **T-#-B-DAC** it is correct

my question is why **\x**  is showing there ?

Comment: I dont think that create any problem the po output is : correct that what you want

Comment: @Mile Alter did you find any solution for this, I am facing similar issue and none of the answers here worked for me.

Comment: @MilanGupta in my case the problem is ,when i copy that text one hidden character also copied don't know how , i was not able to eliminate that with character set , solution : i typed text with keyboard and that  works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit :-** I got your solution ,  you can't able to see but , try to delete "**-**" before **#** , it will first delete one space and then your "**-**" will be deleted. so, it will take one white space before #

And, According to apple document , check

[NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/)

[image]

so, it will take white space before #  just delete it once you will get desire output when you debug.

I hope this info will be helpful for you.

**Edit :-**

[image]

Write this in your x-code ,

```
NSString *strCrown2 = @"T-#-B-DAC";
```

Comment: tried but Same result -> NSString *strCrown2 = @"T#-B-DAC";

Comment: have you removed one white space ?

Comment: still adding \x10 there

Comment: there is no white space

Comment: there is . just try to delete - before # , so it will delete one space .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110228/discussion-between-badal-shah-and-pkt).

Answer (score 1):

Because **#** is for prefix of **hex color**

You can solve it by escape sequence

```
NSString *strCrown2 = @"T-\#-B-DAC";

strCrown2 = [strCrown2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\#" withString:@"200"];//outout:@"T-200-B-DAC"
```

You can also only # not considering '\x' value like the below

```
 NSString *strCrown2 = @"T-#-B-DAC";
 strCrown2 = [strCrown2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@"200"];//outout:@"T-200-B-DAC"
```

Comment: Does it create problem in future  ?

Comment: you need to add \# for printing # as a string

Comment: why you worried about NSLog the string object that you want that show the correct output then why you worried?

Answer (score 0):

The \x is used for hexadecimal representation of a number.

You can follow link for string specifiers [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943-CJBEAEHH)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried same string, may be you are not using x-code 7.
I am not getting as like you , i think it is showing the unicode string.
you can add the string in the `info.plist` . it will work.

[image]

Comment: - Now you got solution But i can't understand , How it is possible Same string in two different ways?

Comment: both are different  strings i checked  length of both and  found that there is one hidden character there so ...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

Before

[image]

After

[image]

i don't know how both string looks same